# Safe to map array to C++ class?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I want to map data from an array to a C++ class. The class will ONLY have private member variables, no inheritance or virtual stuff. Is this safe or should I use a struct in C++?

```
void main(void)
{
    uint8_t data[50];
    MyClass *msg;

    msg = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    msg = (MyClass *) &data[0];

    cout << msg->name();
}
```

The class looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int name;

public:
    int name();        //Getter
    void setName();    //Setter
};
```

Comment: `msg = new MyClass();` what is the point of this line? If you want to initialise `msg` before assigning it properly just assign it to `nullptr`, as it stands you are leaking memory.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read on the subject of serialization, particularly from the boost library. Much safer than copying a struct/class in binary, and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for standard layout types but you need to consider alignment was well:

```
constexpr int bufmax = 50*sizeof(MyClass);
alignas(X) char buffer[bufmax];
```

However just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe to use a `uint8_t[]` as a storage buffer if that's what you're asking, yes. A valid use would look something like this:

```
constexpr size_t array_size = 5;
alignas(MyClass) uint8_t data[sizeof(MyClass) * array_size ];
MyClass *msg = new(data) MyClass[array_size];
```

Then you can use `msg` however you'd like. Your usage is incorrect - if you populate `data` with `uint8_t` values, you cannot access it as if it were a `MyClass`. That would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: The only difference I see here is that you guarantee that data[] is the same size as the class?

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  You've overlooked alignment at least, and I'm pretty sure all binary format guarantees go away if the class isn't a `standard-layout` type.  IE, the compiler can rearrange members at will.

Comment: @RedAlert: Uh, alignment is very relevant.  `sizeof(MyClass)` guarantees you _the right number_ of bytes.  It does not guarantee they are aligned in _the right place in memory_.  `double` in x64 has to be aligned on a 8 byte mark, but your code doesn't guarantee that `data` starts at an 8 byte mark.